# recalling the positions of EVERY word in a list (or even a dictionary)

Tags: python

i'm having trouble with something at the moment. i need my code to recall the positions of every word in a list and print it and i have no idea where to start.

so say i input: "i like cheese because its cheese" i would need it to print the positions of all the words so it would print something like "0, 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,3". could someone help?

i am sure i need to use "len" or "dictionaries" but im not sure how

```
    words = input("Sentence here:")
    word = input("Word here:")
    print ([i + 1 for i in range(len(words.split(" "))) if words.split(" ")[i].lower() == word.lower()])
#i know this prints the postions of a single selected word from the list but im sure i may have to use the same concept?
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear but it seems like you're looking for something like this:

```
sentence = input("Sentence here:")
words = sentence.split()
for i in words:
    print(i + ": " + str(sentence.find(i)))
```

Or if you want to print out the numbers separated by commas like you showed in your question, just save the numbers to a list and then print them together after the for loop.

Comment: thanks, but when i tested this code it  always printed "0 2 7" (on separate lines of course) then other almost random numbers. also sorry if it was a bit unclear i was a bit unsure of how to word it.

Comment: @NothingExistshere It prints the index of the first letter of the word. I think I understand now that you wanted the position (in relation to the other words not the letters) of the first occurrence of the word to be printed out, not the letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to store  the first position of all the distinct words.

```
 words = input("Sentence here:")   
 allwords = words.split(" ");

 mydict = dict()
for i in range(len(allwords)):
     if allwords[i] not in mydict.keys():
          mydict[allwords[i]] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> s = 'i like cheese because its cheese'
>>> words = s.split()
>>> list(map(words.index, words))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

I have written the code in C# which i prefer. You may use the logic in your language. 
Logic : 
a) Store the individual words in a dictionary. This dictionary stores the key as a word from the sentence and its index as its value.

```
Dictionary<string,int> _indexes = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

Key = word and Value = position of the word. Do care of duplicates in this. 
 If the word already exists , dont store that in the dictionary.

b) split the sentence into individual words using a splitter provider by your language.

c) Insert each word ,unless its a duplicate in the dictionary, as the key and its index as the value of the Key.Value pair.

d) Get the word and print the index as the value of the word in the dictionary if its exists.

Code :

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the sentence below :");
        string sentence = Console.ReadLine();

        var helper = new FindWordPosition();
        helper.StoreWordIndexes(sentence);

        Console.WriteLine("Type a word and find out its index");

        string word = Console.ReadLine();

        helper.PrintPosition(word);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}

public class FindWordPosition
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _indexes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void StoreWordIndexes(string sentence)
    {
        string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

        int count = 0;

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (!_indexes.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                _indexes.Add(word, count);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    public void PrintPosition(string word)
    {
        if (!_indexes.ContainsKey(word))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Word doesnot exist in the sentence");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Position of the word {0} is {1}", word, _indexes[word]);
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.